# angularjs route doesn't work with symfony

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I am using symfony 2 in the back-end, and angularjs in the front-end.
When I try angular route, it doesn't work.
Here is my app.js

```
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider

    // route for the home page
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl : '/Resources/views/Default/home.html.twig',
        controller  : 'mainController'
    })

    // route for the about page
    .when('/about', {
        templateUrl : '/Resources/views/Default/about.html.twig',
        controller  : 'aboutController'
    })

    // route for the contact page
    .when('/contact', {
        templateUrl : '/Resources/views/Default/contact.html.twig',
        controller  : 'contactController'
    });
  });
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: What exactly the "doesn't work" mean? Is there any error in console?

Comment: no, i doesn't have any error, but page doesn't change. i mean: when i click on link /about, nothing happen

Comment: Do you use `ng-view`?

Comment: @runTarm: think templateUrl dont find twig file, i try but i dont fix it :sad:
yes, i have ng-view

Comment: If it failed to load the template in templateUrl, there should be an error in console. May be try checking in network tab of DevTools.

Comment: Are you actually able to view template `/Resources/views/Default/about.html.twig` in your browser when entering manually in url?

Comment: @runTarm: yeah, i check it. and it here: GET http://localhost/projects/trilife/web/app_dev.php/about.html.twig 404 (Not Found), so i must created a route in the back-end??

Comment: @RahilWazir: it is error, i think templateUrl just a link to a file?

Comment: @user3581044 If browser did represent the template then there will no issue to load the template by angular. As you said it is error then you have to handle in server-side code to map your URL for the template.

Comment: @RahilWazir but in console it get error 
GET http://localhost/projects/trilife/web/app_dev.php/home.html.twig 404 (Not Found) 
i think templateUrl dont match the file :sad:

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get twig templates in your ngView directive.
Your Angular main app.js should be placed in your assets folder (web/bundles/yourbundle/js/).

If is it, in your angular route declaration, the path of your templates is wrong.
Your current browsing url is `/` and you try to call a template placed in `/src/Namespace/YourBundle/Resources/views/*.html.twig` using only `/Resources/views/*.html.twig`, so it's normal you got an error.

So :

1) You must call your templates using the good complete path

Your application host start at `/` and location is `/web/app_dev.php`

To call templates placed in your bundle resources, you must do something like :

```
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'http://localhost/projects/trilife/src/namespace/YourBundle/Resources/views/Default/home.html.twig',
    controller  : 'mainController'
})
```

But it's a very bad practice to call your server side files from client.

2) Your Angular templates location is wrong

AngularJS is client side, and you try to call templates from the heart of your server side application. your ngRoute templates should be accessible in the `/web` folder only. So place it in your bundle `Resources/public` folder and access it from the `/` browsing url.

3) Cannot use Twig templates in ngView/ngRoute

Angular is client side, and PHP is server side (interpreted language).
If you call twig templates after the page is loaded, your PHP will not be interpreted, so all variables called using twig curly braces will not be rendered. You should use `.html`or other markup extensions.

After make this changes, your application should works fine.